# Problems launching the app from “recent apps” and tapping app icon homescreen

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity

I have an application that starts with a "SplashScreen" and when it finishes it goes to "MainScreen".

I am on "MainScreen" and I click on the home button:

**CASE 1.** I click on "Overview" (the button that shows the recent apps) and I click on my application and simply continue where it was, ie on MainScreen.

**CASE 2.** But If I click on app icon from desktop/home screen this launches the application from zero, ie calls SplashScreen.

**I want it if I hit the icon from desktop this call the last activity as it does "recent apps.**

SPLASHSCREEN:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,ClearTaskOnLaunch = true,

        AlwaysRetainTaskState = false, ExcludeFromRecents = true, NoHistory = true, 
        Label = "MyApp", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/Theme.FullScreen", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

I call "MainScreen" like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
                StartActivity(intent);
                OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.fade_in_animation, Resource.Animation.fade_out_animation);
                this.Finish();
                OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.fade_in_animation, Resource.Animation.fade_out_animation);
```

And MainScreen:

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = false, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
        AlwaysRetainTaskState = true, ExcludeFromRecents = false, NoHistory = false,
        Label = "MyApp", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.FullScreen")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it if I hit the icon from desktop this call the last activity as it does "recent apps.

1. When you set `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance` attribute  for your `SplashScreen`, every time user click the the app icon in the home screen, your app will start with `SplashScreen`.
2. Attribute `ClearTaskOnLaunch = true` means whether or not all activities will be removed from the task, except for the root activity, whenever it is re-launched from the home screen. Please note that : **When the value is "true", every time users start the task again, they are brought to its root activity regardless of what they were last doing in the task and regardless of whether they used the Back or Home button to leave it.**
3. Set [ExcludeFromRecents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html?hl=en-us) to false or remove this attribute, your app icon will display on the "recent apps", like the document said :

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

Remove this attribute from your `SplashScreen`, you could implement this function.